# Openweatherapp API to show 400 error on invalid input in React

Tags: json, reactjs, error-handling, http-status-code-400, openweathermap

I am currently working on a weather application connected to OpenWeatherMap API in React. The problem is that if a user's input is invalid (i.e. they type "Lamdon" instead of "London", the API cannot get any such city (well, obviously) and the whole application crashes. I tried to catch the error but did not manage to do so.

This is the App component:

```
    class App extends Component {
  state = {
    temperature: undefined,
    city: undefined,
    humidity: undefined,
    description: undefined,
    icon: undefined,
    error: undefined
  };

  getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;

    const api_call = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
    const data = await api_call.json();

    if(city) {
      this.setState({
        temperature: Math.round(data.main.temp),
        city: data.name,
        humidity: data.main.humidity,
        description: data.weather[0].description,
        icon: "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png",
        error: ""
      });
    } else if (!city) {
      this.setState({
        temperature: undefined,
        city: undefined,
        humidity: undefined,
        description: undefined,
        icon: undefined,
        error: "Please enter a correct city name"
      });

    }
      else {
      this.setState({
        temperature: undefined,
        city: undefined,
        humidity: undefined,
        description: undefined,
        icon: undefined,
        error: "Please enter the value"
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Weather application</h1>
        <span className="lead">Get current weather of your location</span>
        <Form getWeather={this.getWeather}/>
        <Weather
          temperature={this.state.temperature}
          city={this.state.city}
          humidity={this.state.humidity}
          description={this.state.description}
          icon={this.state.icon}
          error={this.state.error}
        />
        </div>
    );
  };
};
```

Comment: Did you try `const api_call = ...;` with a try-catch?

Comment: Promises rejected will be caught in catch phase. In this case http 400 returns a rejected promise

Comment: Oh my god, you are the best! Thank you!!

Comment: Works like a charm :)